# Can I add OpenCycleMap to ArcGIS Explorer Desktop?

Tags: openstreetmap, arcgis-explorer

I'm using the ArcGIS Explorer Desktop (free viewer) - build 1750 (latest).
It comes with several built in base maps, including OpenStreetMap.
Is it possible to add to it OpenCycleMap:
http://www.opencyclemap.org/
as well ?

Answer (score 1):

To have OpenCycleMap added to ArcGIS Online would involve asking Esri if that would be possible to do.  You could do this via its [contact form](http://www.esri.com/about-esri/contact.html) or by submitting an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/) (which I would vote for).

An alternative is that ArcGIS Explorer Desktop supports WMS, so if you could find someone providing a service URL for an OpenCycleMap WMS then this could be added via **Add Content | GIS Services** then setting **Server Type: WMS**.  I've just looked quickly for an OpenCycleMap WMS without success.  If you are in Great Britain then the [OSM-GB](http://www.osmgb.org.uk/osm-gb-wiki/index.php/WMS) project could be worth contacting.